# StreamController works differently for different cases flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have defined this inside initstate:

```
uploadController.stream.listen((event) async {
      setState(() {
        uploads++;
      });
      print("inside 1");
      await event();
      print("Inside 2");
      setState(() {
        uploads--;
      });
    });
```

And here is how i am adding an event:

```
uploadController.add(
        // () async {
        //   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
        // }
        uploadVideos(
          rid: widget.rid,
          groupId: widget.data.groupId!,
          pId: widget.data.userId!,
          token: token,
          mediaPath: widget.data.mediaPath,
          username: widget.data.username,
        )
    );
```

When I use dummy function, it works fine, but when I call the main funciton, it doesn't work, why?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a very vague term. Please tell us more. What does it mean when you say it doesn't work? Does it crash? Do the prints happen? What exactly happens and what did you expect it to happen?